# How to replace properly text with new line sign in text file using VBA?

Tags: vba, text, replace, line-breaks

I am trying to replace some text including line break, however it doesn't work. Was using Chr(10), Chr(13) and combination Chr(10)+Chr(13). None works. Any ideas? Code below:

```
Sub Replacetext()

 Dim MyFolder As String
 Dim MyFile As String
 Dim Fname As String


 MyFolder = "D:\Excel" 
 MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.txt")

 Do While MyFile <> ""
 Fname = MyFolder & "\" & MyFile
 Workbooks.OpenText Fname

 Cells.Replace What:="a" & Chr(13) & "a", Replacement:="b" & Chr(13) & "b" _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False, lookat:=xlWhole

 ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=1
 MyFile = Dir
 Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use `vbCrLf`? That should match a new line on a dos formatted file. Is your text file from a Unix system?

Comment: Doesn't work. Text file is manually created in Windows OS.

Comment: There is also this that when I try to replace text without line break, with a text containing line break I get additional ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer**

The ANSI code you are looking for is just `10`

**Longer Answer**

Ok, So maybe this will help you. I created multiline data in a cell like this:

```
This is
Multiline
```

In `"A1"`. Then I wanted to see what the code(s) of the whitespace were.

```
Public Sub ToAnsi()
    Dim strCellData As String
    strCellData = Range("A1").Value

    For i = 1 To Len(strCellData)
        MsgBox Asc(Mid$(strCellData, i, 1))
    Next
End Sub
```

Not elegant by an means but we get the answer from the MsgBox. I was able to ascertain that the newline whitespace code was `10`. Which was a surprise to me. My test was on Excel 2010.

**Update**

I have noticed you are missing a trailing comma in the first line of your `Cells.replace`. So it should be:

```
Cells.Replace What:="a" & Chr(13) & "a", Replacement:="b" & Chr(13) & "b", _
```

Also consider the following data. Row one contains multiline data.

```
     A           B          C
1    This is     a
     Multiline   a  
2
```

If I run your code against my sheet with my ANSI numbers and even edit cell `C1` with similar data.

```
Range("C1").Value = "c" & Chr(10) & "c"
Cells.Replace What:="a" & Chr(10) & "a", Replacement:="b" & Chr(10) & "b", _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False, lookat:=xlWhole

     A           B          C
1    This is     b          c
     Multiline   b          c   
2
```

If it is not working for you I think you need some more debugging or more information. Also here is a picture in case the formatting of *"cells"* isnt the best.

[image]

Comment: I will test your code against a multiline cell. I will replace and a with a after a newline. Check your syntax as per my updated answer. Although i doubt that's your ultimate issue. Also you should try to break down one of your cells as i have for testing.

Comment: Yes it works in situation you depicted. However now I see that my problem is with loading text file. How to load text file in one cell instead of multiple cells.

Comment: Read the file as a textstream using ReadAll then you could place it into a cell. Like [here](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/faq/FileSystemObject/faq2.shtml). If you are having issues with that please make a new question.